# contact form, and public server

Tags: php, html, sql-server, localhost

im having a problem here, a little unexpected. I did a basic contact form for my website, php code. Its all working well, but when i transfered to my public server, appears this, all messed up, literally like this:

```
    25 || strlen($contacto_email)>50 || strlen($contacto_mensagem)>1000) { echo 'Desculpe, o tamanho de um dos campos foi ultrapassado.'; } else { $to = 'info@bridgeid.com
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
'; $subject = 'submetido.'; $body = $contacto_nome."\n".$contacto_mensagem; $headers = 'Form: '.$contacto_email; if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { echo 'Obrigado por nos ter contactado. Responderemos assim que possível.';     } else { echo 'Pedimos desculpa, ocorreu um erro. Por favor tente mais tarde.'; } } } else { echo 'Todos os campos precisam de ser preenchidos.'; } } ?>
```

But in my localhost it all working properly and well.

I dont know if there´s some way that the public server is not compatible with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your webhost actually supports PHP. I see that question is tagged with `sql-server` which assumes a windows hosting environment.

Even though IIS (which runs on windows) can support PHP you need to make sure that your host actually allows this as this is not a typical scenario.

1. Check your webhosting documentation and make sure PHP is supported
2. If you're not sure then just send an email to their support team and ask ;)